# C++: Attempting to "write" or "send" from server-side socket returns -1 after several hundred requests

Tags: c++, sockets, berkeley-sockets

I have written the code for a basic server in C++ using the `sys/socket.h` header. The method which runs the server and responds to requests is shown below. Code runs in a continuous loop so long as a member variable (`Server::keep_server_` is set to true). Upon receiving a JSON request, it looks up the appropriate handler from a map, calls it to generate a JSON response, and `send`/`write`s that back to the client:

```
    /**
    * Run server, listen for client requests, send responses.
    */
    void Run() {
        int sock_fd, client_sock;
        struct sockaddr_in server{}, client{};

        if ((sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Socket creation failed.");
        }

        int enable = 1;
        setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int));

        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server.sin_port = htons(port_);

        // Bind socket.
        if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Socket bind failed.");
        }

        // Listen and accept incoming connections.
        listen(sock_fd, max_clients_);
        listening_ = true;
        int c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        // Char buffer to which clients requests will be written.
        char client_req[2048];
        // JSON parser and serializer.
        JSONCPP_STRING parse_err;

        while ((client_sock = accept(sock_fd,
                                     (struct sockaddr *) &client,
                                     (socklen_t *) &c))
               && keep_server_)
        {
            // JSON objects to hold parsed request and serialized response.
            Json::Value json_req, json_resp;
            json_resp["SUCCESS"] = true;

            if (client_sock < 0) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Socket accept failed.");
            }

            bzero(client_req, 2048);
            long req_size = recv(client_sock, client_req, 2048, 0);

            if (req_size > 0) {
                std::string client_req_str(client_req);
                // Read clientReq as JSON first, write response to json_resp.
                if (reader_->parse(client_req_str.c_str(),
                                   client_req_str.c_str() +
                                   client_req_str.length(),
                                   &json_req, &parse_err))
                {
                    try {
                        // Get JSON response.
                        json_resp = ProcessRequest(json_req);
                    } catch (const std::exception &ex) {
                        // If json parsing failed.
                        json_resp["SUCCESS"] = false;
                        json_resp["ERRORS"] = std::string(ex.what());
                    }
                } else {
                    // If json parsing failed.
                    json_resp["SUCCESS"] = false;
                    json_resp["ERRORS"] = std::string(parse_err);
                }

                std::string resp = Json::writeString(writer_, json_resp);
                if(send(client_sock, strdup(resp.c_str()), MAX_SOCKET_WRITE, 0) == -1)
                    throw std::runtime_error("Socket write failed.");
            } else if (req_size == -1) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Socket receive failed.");
            }
        }

        listening_ = false;
        close(sock_fd);
    }
```

This code functions just as intended for several hundred cycles of requests and responses, at which point `send` or `write` (I have tried with both, they each experience the same issue) returns `-1`, and the process exits.

Why would socket writes suddenly fail after working for so long? How should I deal with this?

EDIT: To clarify, all client/server activity is being run locally (i.e. they are just two different threads on my machine).

EDIT 2: The `errno` is 14, which is apparently "bad file descriptor".

EDIT 3: Another user recommended providing a minimum reproducible example. The error seems to be triggered by repeatedly sending requests to the server.

To fulfill this, I will first offer the full code for my server class, a template class which takes a certain class as a template parameter. The server, in its construction, is passed an instance of this class along with a number of `std::mem_fn`s from the class, which it binds to certain command types. The server subsequently handles requests by calling the relevant handlers on the instance of the template parameter class provided:

```
[SERVER.H]
#pragma once
#ifndef CHORD_FINAL_SERVER
#define CHORD_FINAL_SERVER

/// When reading from / writing to sockets, it's best to just read/write as many chars as possible.
/// We'll just define this for as a macro.
#define MAX_SOCKET_WRITE 999999

#include <json/json.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <functional>

/**
 * A simple server which responds to requests using a pre-defined set of methods.
 *
 * @tparam RequestHandler Type of the method responding to requests.
 * @tparam RequestClass The class for which Request Handler is a method.
 */
template<class RequestHandler, class RequestClass>
class Server {
public:
    /**
    * Initialize server object. (Does not run server or listen for reqs.)
    *
    * @param port Port on which to run server.
    * @param commands A map of request strings (sent by clients) to function ptrs
    * to handle them.
    */
    Server(int port, int max_clients,
           const std::map<std::string, RequestHandler> *commands,
           RequestClass *request_class_inst) :
            port_(port),
            max_clients_(max_clients),
            commands_(*commands),
            request_class_inst_(request_class_inst),
            keep_server_(true),
            listening_(false),
            reader_((new Json::CharReaderBuilder)->newCharReader()) {}

    /**
    * Run server, listen for client requests, send responses.
    */
    void Run() {
        int sock_fd, client_sock;
        struct sockaddr_in server{}, client{};

        if ((sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Socket creation failed.");
        }

        int enable = 1;
        setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int));

        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server.sin_port = htons(port_);

        // Bind socket.
        if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Socket bind failed.");
        }

        // Listen and accept incoming connections.
        if(listen(sock_fd, max_clients_) < 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("Listen failed");

        listening_ = true;
        int c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        // Char buffer to which clients requests will be written.
        char client_req[2048];
        // JSON parser and serializer.
        JSONCPP_STRING parse_err;

        while ((client_sock = accept(sock_fd,
                                     (struct sockaddr *) &client,
                                     (socklen_t *) &c))
               && keep_server_)
        {
            // JSON objects to hold parsed request and serialized response.
            Json::Value json_req, json_resp;
            json_resp["SUCCESS"] = true;

            if (client_sock < 0) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Socket accept failed.");
            }

            bzero(client_req, 2048);
            long req_size = recv(client_sock, client_req, 2048, 0);

            if (req_size > 0) {
                std::string client_req_str(client_req);
                // Read clientReq as JSON first, write response to json_resp.
                if (reader_->parse(client_req_str.c_str(),
                                   client_req_str.c_str() +
                                   client_req_str.length(),
                                   &json_req, &parse_err))
                {
                    try {
                        // Get JSON response.
                        json_resp = ProcessRequest(json_req);
                    } catch (const std::exception &ex) {
                        // If json parsing failed.
                        json_resp["SUCCESS"] = false;
                        json_resp["ERRORS"] = std::string(ex.what());
                    }
                } else {
                    // If json parsing failed.
                    json_resp["SUCCESS"] = false;
                    json_resp["ERRORS"] = std::string(parse_err);
                }

                std::string resp = Json::writeString(writer_, json_resp);
                errno = 0;
                if(send(client_sock, strdup(resp.c_str()), MAX_SOCKET_WRITE, 0) == -1) {
                    std::cout << "ERRNO " << errno << std::endl;
                    throw std::runtime_error("Socket write failed.");
                }
            } else if (req_size == -1) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Socket receive failed.");
            }

            if(close(client_sock) < 0)
                throw std::runtime_error("Socket close error");
        }

        listening_ = false;
        close(sock_fd);
    }

    /**
    * Run server as daemon.
    */
    void RunInBackground()
    {
        std::thread t([this] { Run(); });
        t.detach();
    }

    /**
    * Kill server, whether it runs in a detached thread or the main one.
    */
    void Kill()
    {
        keep_server_ = false;
    }

    /// Set to true when server has begun listening.
    bool listening_;

protected:
    /// Since the commands in commands are methods, this is the "this" we pass to them.
    RequestClass *request_class_inst_;

    /// Port on which server runs.
    const int port_;

    /// Maximum clients for which server will listen.
    const int max_clients_;

    /// When "true", server thread will continue running in background. When set
    /// to 0, server dies.
    bool keep_server_;

    /// A map of potential server commands (sent by clients) to RequestHandlers
    /// (func ptrs).
    std::map<std::string, RequestHandler> commands_;

    /**
    * Take a client's JSON request, generate an appropriate JSON response.
    *
    * @param request JSON object outlining request from a client to this server.
    * @return a JSON object to be transmitted as a response to the client's req,
    *          with a key "SUCCESS" set to either 1 or 0 to indicate whether
    *          request was valid and succesffully executed, along with any
    *          other relevant return info from the request.
    */
    Json::Value ProcessRequest(Json::Value request)
    {
        Json::Value response;
        std::string command = request["COMMAND"].asString();

        // If command is not valid, give a response with an error.
        if(commands_.find(command) == commands_.end()) {
            response["SUCCESS"] = false;
            response["ERRORS"] = "Invalid command.";
        }
            // Otherwise, run the relevant handler.
        else {
            RequestHandler handler = commands_.at(command);
            response = handler(*request_class_inst_, request);
        }

        return response;
    }

private:
    /// Reads JSON.
    const std::unique_ptr<Json::CharReader> reader_;
    /// Writes JSON.
    Json::StreamWriterBuilder writer_;
};

#endif
```

I also define a basic client class as follows:

```
[CLIENT.H]
#pragma once
#ifndef CHORD_FINAL_CLIENT_H
#define CHORD_FINAL_CLIENT_H

#include <json/json.h>

class Client {
public:
    /**
     * Constructor, initializes JSON parser and serializer.
     */
    Client();

    /**
     * Send a request to a server at a given port-IP pairing.
     *
     * @param recipient_ip IP to send request to.
     * @param port Port to send request to.
     * @param request JSON object detailing request to server.
     * @return JSON response from server or throw an error.
     */
    Json::Value make_request(const char *recipient_ip, int port, const Json::Value &request);

    /**
     * Determine whether or not a node is alive.
     *
     * @param ip_addr IP address of node to ping.
     * @param port Port of node to ping
     * @return Value of whether or not a server is running on ip_addr:port.
     */
    static bool is_alive(const char *ip_addr, int port);

protected:
    /// Reads JSON.
    const std::unique_ptr<Json::CharReader> reader_;
    /// Writes JSON.
    Json::StreamWriterBuilder writer_;
};


#endif //CHORD_FINAL_CLIENT_H
```

```
[CLIENT.CPP]
#include "client.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <thread>

Client::Client()
        : reader_((new Json::CharReaderBuilder)->newCharReader())
{}

Json::Value Client::make_request(const char *recipient_ip, int port,
                                 const Json::Value &request)
{
    int sock_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in destination{};

    if ((sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Socket creation failed");
    }
    destination.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(recipient_ip);
    destination.sin_family = AF_INET;
    destination.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &destination, sizeof(destination)) < 0) {
        close(sock_fd);
        throw std::runtime_error("Host " + std::string(recipient_ip) +
                                 + ":" + std::to_string(port) + " down.");
    }

    std::string serialized_req = Json::writeString(writer_, request);
    if (send(sock_fd, serialized_req.c_str(), strlen(serialized_req.c_str()), 0) < 0) {
        close(sock_fd);
        throw std::runtime_error("Socket write failed.");
    }

    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv);

    char resp_buff[2048];
    if (recv(sock_fd, resp_buff, 2048, 0) < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Socket receive error.");
    }

    Json::Value json_resp;
    JSONCPP_STRING parse_err;
    std::string resp_str(resp_buff);
    if (reader_->parse(resp_str.c_str(), resp_str.c_str() + resp_str.length(),
                      &json_resp, &parse_err))
    {
        close(sock_fd);
        return json_resp;
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("Error parsing response.");
}

bool Client::is_alive(const char *ip_addr, int port)
{
    int sock_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in destination{};

    if ((sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Socket creation failed");
    }
    destination.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_addr);
    destination.sin_family = AF_INET;
    destination.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &destination, sizeof(destination)) < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

To reproduce my issue, you only need to define a basic server type with methods designed to handle JSON requests:

```
/// NOTE: This class exists exclusively for unit testing.
class RequestClass {
public:
    /**
     * Initialize class with value n to add sub from input values.
     *
     * @param n Value to add/sub from input values.
     */
    explicit RequestClass(int n) : n_(n) {}

    /// Value to add/sub from
    int n_;

    /**
     * Add n to value in JSON request.
     *
     * @param request JSON request with field "value".
     * @return JSON response containing modified field "value" = [original_value] + n.
     */
    [[nodiscard]] Json::Value add_n(const Json::Value &request) const
    {
        Json::Value resp;
        resp["SUCCESS"] = true;

        // If value is present in request, return value + 1, else return error.
        if (request.get("VALUE", NULL) != NULL) {
            resp["VALUE"] = request["VALUE"].asInt() + this->n_;
        } else {
            resp["SUCCESS"] = false;
            resp["ERRORS"] = "Invalid value.";
        }
        return resp;
    }

    /**
     * Sun n from value in JSON request.
     *
     * @param request JSON request with field "value".
     * @return JSON response containing modified field "value" = [original_value] - n.
     */
    [[nodiscard]] Json::Value sub_n(const Json::Value &request) const
    {
        Json::Value resp, value;
        resp["SUCCESS"] = true;

        // If value is present in request, return value + 1, else return error.
        if (request.get("VALUE", NULL) != NULL) {
            resp["VALUE"] = request["VALUE"].asInt() - this->n_;
        } else {
            resp["SUCCESS"] = false;
            resp["ERRORS"] = "Invalid value.";
        }
        return resp;
    }
};
```

Then, instantiate a server mapping methods to command strings. Send it a large number of requests, and, within less than a second, `send` or `write` will return -1, causing the program to throw a runtime error:

```
    Server<RequestClassMethod, RequestClass> *server_;
    auto *request_inst = new RequestClass(1);
    std::map<std::string, RequestClassMethod> commands {{"ADD_1", std::mem_fn(&RequestClass::add_n)},
                                                        {"SUB_1", std::mem_fn(&RequestClass::sub_n)}};
    server_ = new Server<RequestClassMethod, RequestClass>(5000, 50, &commands, request_inst);
    server_->RunInBackground();
    // Since the server is running in a new thread, spin until it completes setup.
    while(! server_->listening_) {}
    Client *request_maker_ = new Client;

    // Formulate request asking for value of 1 - 1.
    Json::Value sub_one_req;
    sub_one_req["COMMAND"] = "SUB_1";
    sub_one_req["VALUE"] = 1;

    // Send request, expect value of 0 and successful return code.
    Json::Value sub_one_resp = request_maker_->make_request("127.0.0.1", 5000, sub_one_req);
    while(true) {
        Json::Value sub_one_resp = request_maker_->make_request("127.0.0.1", 5000, sub_one_req);
    }
```

Hopefully this is sufficient to reproduce. Sorry if the question was ill-formed previously.

EDIT 4: It occurred to me that this could be a problem pertaining to max file descriptors per program. However, my program completes exactly 2031 request-response cycles before failing. This doesn't seem in line with the max file descriptor cap.

Comment: What's the `errno`?

Comment: @o11c Errno is 14, which is apparently `bad file descriptor`.

Comment: Hmm, on my system errno 14 is EFAULT ... what OS and architecture are you using? Anyway, a very brief scan over your code shows a LOT of return values not being checked. You've probably had some prior call fail and that's what the next failure is caused by.

Comment: @CharlesBuchanan It looks like you're not checking the return value on _every_ call. Do that and print the error message if any call fails. It will give you hints.

Comment: @o11c OS is debian. It seems unlikely to me that a call prior to `write` failed, since the server receives the correct request and generates the correct response. What values should I be checking that I'm not? I make sure that `send` doesn't return -1, I make sure that `recv` returns a value greater than 0, and I  make sure that `accept` is greater than 0. Sorry if this is obvious, I'm pretty inexperienced with the sockets API.

Comment: I don't see any closing of the client sockets?

Comment: @AlanBirtles So, I tried adding `close(client_sock)` as the final line of the `while` loop. I still get the same error at the same spot.

Comment: @CharlesBuchanan What happens if you check the return value of _every_ function call?

Comment: For a start, extract a [mcve]. The reason may well be outside of the code you show here, which makes this discussion futile. Then, any operation you perform should have its results checked if success/failure is signalled with return codes or via `errno`. Convert those to exceptions right away, so you have a solid base that no error happens unnoticed. Further, use RAII on any resource that doesn't use that already. That said, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: So, I revised my code slightly. I now close `client_sock` at the end of each loop and check its return, and I check the value of `listen` before the program enters the loop. Other than that, I'm not sure which functions I'm failing to check. The program still receives a `-1` when `write` is called, causing it to fail.

Comment: 14 is EFAULT, which means you are passing a bad address to `write`. Use your debugger, stop at the point where `write` returns -1, and study the parameters you pass to it.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. When I look at the values of `client_sock`, I see that they gradually increase, beginning at 4 and ending at 2017. After about a dozen uses of 2017 as `client_sock`, the failure occurs. I'm not sure if this indicates anything useful.

Comment: "they gradually increase, beginning at 4 and ending at 2017" This probably means you are not closing the socket.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. So, you were correct. I added a line to `close` the sock_fd in the client call, and now the program simply opens the same file descriptor over and over (4). However, I still receive errno 14 with the `write` call.

Comment: *14 is EFAULT, which means you are passing a bad address to write. Use your debugger, stop at the point where write returns -1, and study the parameters you pass to it.*